# Wordpress CSS head info - contents, expansions?

Tags: css

AFAIK a `style.css` for Wordpress needs some comments at the top to be properly recognized, like:

```
/* Theme Name: Cool Theme
 Theme URI:     http://www.example.com
 Description:   Super cool theme */
```

Are there any restrictions regarding content? I've also seen people writing stuff in there like

```
@author Michael Jordan
@copyright 1990 by me
```

What's up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to add something not listed in [WP_Theme class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php) `$file_headers` array because it simply will not be recognized.

```
private static $file_headers = array(
        'Name'        => 'Theme Name',
        'ThemeURI'    => 'Theme URI',
        'Description' => 'Description',
        'Author'      => 'Author',
        'AuthorURI'   => 'Author URI',
        'Version'     => 'Version',
        'Template'    => 'Template',
        'Status'      => 'Status',
        'Tags'        => 'Tags',
        'TextDomain'  => 'Text Domain',
        'DomainPath'  => 'Domain Path',
);
```